# Select records in the previous 12 hour window

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have table in below structure,

```
Id      Name      Created_Date
1       AAA       10/20/2019 3:00:00
2       BBB       10/20/2019 15:00:00
3       CCC       10/21/2019 4:00:00
4       DDD       10/21/2019 18:00:00
```

I need single query that needs to return based on current date and time, For example:

Case 1: Current Date is 10/21/2019 and time is in AM, It needs to return Previous date (10/20/2019), Second half(10/20/2019 12:00:01 to 10/20/2019 23:59:59).
In our case, Record "BBB" needs to be return.

Case 2: Current Date is 10/21/2019 and time is in PM, It needs to return current date (10/21/2019), First half(10/21/2019 00:00:01 to 10/21/2019 11:59:59).
In our case, Record "CCC" needs to be return.

Comment: What is the datatype of Created_Date? datetime or datetime2?

Comment: datatype is "datetime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Temp_Table TABLE
(
    Id INT,Name VARCHAR(10),Created_Date DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
SELECT 1,'AAA','10/20/2019 3:00:00 ' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'BBB','10/20/2019 15:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'CCC','10/21/2019 4:00:00 ' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'DDD','10/21/2019 18:00:00' 

DECLARE @DATE_TIME DATETIME='10/21/2019 18:00:00'

SELECT  *
FROM @Temp_Table
WHERE Created_Date BETWEEN IIF(DATEPART(HOUR,@DATE_TIME) >12,CAST(CAST(@DATE_TIME AS DATE) AS DATETIME),DATEADD(HOUR,12,DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(CAST(@DATE_TIME AS DATE) AS DATETIME))))
AND IIF(DATEPART(HOUR,@DATE_TIME) >12,DATEADD(HOUR,12,CAST(CAST(@DATE_TIME AS DATE) AS DATETIME)),CAST(CAST(@DATE_TIME AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT ID,Name, Created_Date
FROM
 (
      SELECT *, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Hour, GETDATE() ,Created_Date) < 0 AND DATEDIFF(Hour, GETDATE() ,Created_Date) >= -12  THEN Created_Date ELSE NULL END AS ComputedColumn
      FROM Tbl
 ) X WHERE ComputedColumn IS NOT NULL
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aca69f63c59ef51ee11ab7576d58d907)**